# Android: How to save custom finger paint view on orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, android-canvas, android-orientation

I'm trying to create a custom view where a user can draw their signature. One where you can put it into the view programmatically and set the size, etc. I haven't had to do this before so I based it off the fingerpaint class from android api demos. Problem right now is that it erases the object on orientation change and I'm not sure how to get it to not do that.

The code for PaintView

```
private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
private boolean mDrawPoint;

private int stateToSave;

private Paint mPaint;


public PaintView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    System.out.println("init");
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    setupPaint();
}

private void setupPaint()
{
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    System.out.println("w "+w+" h "+h+" oldw "+oldw+" oldh "+oldh);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("on draw");
    canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    mDrawPoint=true;
}
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mDrawPoint=false;
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}
private void touch_up() {
    if(mDrawPoint == true) {
        mCanvas.drawPoint(mX, mY, mPaint);
    } else {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As a mini test I added in

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() 
{
    System.out.println("save instance");
    stateToSave++;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("instanceState", super.onSaveInstanceState());  
    bundle.putInt("stateToSave", this.stateToSave);

    return bundle;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) 
{
    System.out.println("on restore");
    if (state instanceof Bundle) 
    {
        System.out.println("on restore");
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        this.stateToSave = bundle.getInt("stateToSave");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable("instanceState"));
        System.out.println(stateToSave);
        return;
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

But onRestoreInstance() and onSaveInstance() never get called on orientation change. Here is my code in the oncreate in the activity that makes a paintview.

```
RelativeLayout inner= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.inner);

    int width=600;
    int height=360;
    float X= 100;
    float Y=60;

    LayoutParams wrapped = new LayoutParams(width,height);

    PaintView painting=new PaintView(this);

    painting.setX(X);
    painting.setY(Y);
    painting.setLayoutParams(wrapped);
    inner.addView(painting);
```

Edit: I figured it out why saveinstancestate wasn't calling, I had to give the View an ID and then it would work.

painting.setId(4);

Now I need to figure out how to make it save the drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure your View is [saveEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSaveEnabled%28boolean%29), try:

```
setSaveEnabled(true);
```

You could do this from the constructor of your PaintView.

Also, you may need to make sure that your activities are being destroyed/recreated on orientation change. Make sure you **DO NOT** have:

```
<activity name="?"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
/>
```

declared for the activity using this View or else the activity won't be destroyed on orientation change. Also, if you have overridden **onSaveInstanceState**/**onRestoreInstanceState** in those activities you need to call the respective superclass method, either super.onSaveInstanceState() or super.onRestoreInstanceState())

As far as how to actually recreate or save the image for orientation changes how about you  save each event that is done in some kind of parcelable List. Save that list in onSaveInstanceState and restore it in onRestoreInstanceState. THen take the list of events and loop through it, calling the respective draw functions.
You may need to do some translation of X,Y values based on the new orientation.

The code would look something like this:

```
public class PaintView extends View {

    private static final String EXTRA_EVENT_LIST = "event_list";
private static final String EXTRA_STATE = "instance_state";
private ArrayList<MotionEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<MotionEvent>(100);

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);           
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            performTouchEvent(event);                
        }             
        return true;
    }

    private void performTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                break;
                }
                invalidate();
                eventList.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));           
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() 
    {
        System.out.println("save instance");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(EXTRA_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());  
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_EVENT_LIST, eventList);

    return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) 
    {
        if (state instanceof Bundle) 
        {
            Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(EXTRA_STATE));
            eventList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_EVENT_LIST);
            if (eventList == null) {
               eventList = new ArrayList<MotionEvent>(100); 
            }
            for (MotionEvent event : eventList) {
               performTouchEvent(event);
            }               
            return;
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried putting in this.setSaveEnabled(true), still isn't calling public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()

Comment: Check my updated answer, perhaps your activity isn't being destroyed/recreated on orientation change.

Comment: I didn't set an Id for the View which I fixed and it worked. Now I need to figure out how to save the drawing.

Comment: save on rotation I mean

Comment: thanks for that, I cannot work on it right now, but I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: cannot convert from new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>(){} to Parcelable.Creator<PaintView.EventHolder>

Comment: The code above is a rough sketch of what to do it's not tested. I was hoping you would get the premise. The generic types were wrong, i used the example online for creating a parcelable. Should be EventHolder on both sides of assignment operation.

Comment: After I fixed that and moved some stuff around it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped. You should consider upvoting and or accepting this answer if it helped solve your problem (this is how stack overflow works).

Comment: You can also make an ArrayList of the MotionEvent objects (they implement Parcelable). Just make sure to call MotionEven.obtain() when you add the events to the array list.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I cleaned up the code to do as neeraj2608 mentioned

Comment: In my case it recreates one dot in the left corner and when I rotate a second time it throws an ConcurrentModificationException

EDIT: the code is not good alligned: it looks like the `eventList.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));` is in the `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

Comment: It throws an ConcurrentModificationException because `performTouchEvent` adds the event back to the eventlist when calling `performTouchEvent` in `restoreInstanceState()`
You have to use a seprate ArrayList in restoreInstancesState()