# DrawerView is clearing when I rotate a phone

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

When I rotate a phone my `DrawerView` is clearing . When I rotate my phone in my class `DrawerView` is running `onSizeChanged` and after that my drawView is empty. I have added `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in my AndroidManifest  but it doesn't work.

**This is my drawer view :**

```
public class DrawerView extends View {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private float mX, mY, sX, sY;
    private boolean isSigned = false;

    public DrawerView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public DrawerView(Context c, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(c);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mBitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public void setIsSigned(boolean isSigned) {
        this.isSigned = isSigned;
    }

    public boolean isSigned() {
        return isSigned;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    public void clear() {
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void drawDot(float x, float y) {
        mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, 2.0f, mPaint);
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        sX = x;
        sY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.isSigned = true;
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (x == sX && y == sY) {
                    drawDot(x, y);
                }
                touch_up();
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I rotate a phone this is doing and

```
  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);   
  }
```

and my drawer is clearing

this is my whole class :

public class SignatureActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {

```
File mCurrentPhotoPath;
private FrameLayout drawerBox;
private Button save, clear;
private DrawerView mv;
private Paint mPaint;
private boolean existingSign;
private Intent intent;
private String signature;
private File imagesDir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_act_lay);
    existingSign = getIntent().hasExtra(getPackageName() + "_signaturePath");
    initializeView();
    setListeners();
    Intent iin = getIntent();
    Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        signature = (String) b.get("signaturePath");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    finish();
}

private void initializeView() {
    drawerBox = this.findViewById(R.id.drawerContainer);
    save = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
    clear = findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);
    if (existingSign) {
        mv = new DrawerView(this, BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent()
                .getStringExtra(getPackageName() + "_signaturePath")));
    } else {
        mv = new DrawerView(this);
    }
    mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    mv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    drawerBox.addView(mv);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mCurrentPhotoPath = (File) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(MY_CURRENT_PHOTO_PATH_KEY);
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putSerializable(MY_CURRENT_PHOTO_PATH_KEY, mCurrentPhotoPath);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void setListeners() {
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!mv.isSigned()) {
                Toast.makeText(SignatureActivity.this, R.string.empty_sign, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                String name = "sign_" + currentDateandTime;
                Bitmap bitmap = mv.getDrawingCache();
                File imagesFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                imagesFolder.mkdirs();
                File file = new File(imagesFolder, name + ".jpg");
                try {
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                    mv.invalidate();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                }
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra(getPackageName() + "_signaturePath", file.getPath());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

                finishWithResult(file.getPath());
                if (signature != null) {
                    File file1 = new File(signature);
                    file1.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mv.clear();
            mv.setIsSigned(false);
        }
    });

}

private void finishWithResult(String path) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    intent.putExtra("path", path);
    finish();
}


@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    return false;
}


public class DrawerView extends View {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private float mX, mY, sX, sY;
    private boolean isSigned = false;

    public DrawerView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public DrawerView(Context c, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(c);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mBitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public void setIsSigned(boolean isSigned) {
        this.isSigned = isSigned;
    }

    public boolean isSigned() {
        return isSigned;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    public void clear() {
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void drawDot(float x, float y) {
        mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, 2.0f, mPaint);
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        sX = x;
        sY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.isSigned = true;
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (x == sX && y == sY) {
                    drawDot(x, y);
                }
                touch_up();
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could save the touch events in some type of List and then recreate them after configuration changes. [This is already explained in here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19986163/10916407)

Your class should look like this

```
public class DrawerView extends View {
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
private float mX, mY, sX, sY;
private boolean isSigned = false;

private static final String EXTRA_STATE = "exta_state";
private static final String EXTRA_EVENT_LIST = "exta_event_list";


private ArrayList<MotionEvent> motionEvents = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<MotionEvent> auxMotionEvents = new ArrayList<>();

public DrawerView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSaveEnabled(true);
}

public DrawerView(Context c, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(c, attributeSet);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSaveEnabled(true);
}

public DrawerView(Context c, Bitmap bitmap) {
    super(c);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mBitmap = bitmap;
    setSaveEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {



    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(EXTRA_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_EVENT_LIST, motionEvents);

    return bundle;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (state instanceof Bundle) {

        auxMotionEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        motionEvents = new ArrayList<>();

        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(EXTRA_STATE));
        auxMotionEvents = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_EVENT_LIST);
        if (auxMotionEvents == null) {
            auxMotionEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return;
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}

private void performTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    this.isSigned = true;
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (x == sX && y == sY) {
                drawDot(x, y);
            }
            touch_up();
            break;
    }
    invalidate();
    motionEvents.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));
}




public void setIsSigned(boolean isSigned) {
    this.isSigned = isSigned;
}

public boolean isSigned() {
    return isSigned;
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    if (auxMotionEvents != null) {
        for (MotionEvent motionEvent : auxMotionEvents) {
            performTouch(motionEvent);
        }
    }

}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mBitmapPaint);
}

public void clear() {
    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    invalidate();
}

private void drawDot(float x, float y) {
    mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, 2.0f, mBitmapPaint);
}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    sX = x;
    sY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mBitmapPaint);
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mBitmapPaint);
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            performTouch(event);
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Remember to remove android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" from your manisfest and to give the view an id so it can be recreated.

To set an id for your view use setId() after you instantiate DrawerView in your initializeView(). It should look something like this

```
private void initializeView() {
drawerBox = this.findViewById(R.id.drawerContainer);
save = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
clear = findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);
if (existingSign) {
    mv = new DrawerView(this, BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent()
            .getStringExtra(getPackageName() + "_signaturePath")));
} else {
    mv = new DrawerView(this);
}

mv.setId(View.generateViewId());

mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
mv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
drawerBox.addView(mv);
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

}

Comment: this I should added in  onCreate ? setSaveEnabled(true);

Comment: You should add it in the class constructor of your view, or in the attributes of the XML file declaration.

Comment: This is my whole class how should look like :

Comment: You need to modify only you DrawerView class. You need to define setSaveEnabled(true) on the constructors. Then you need to save the list with the touch events on the onSaveInstanceState() and get them on onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state).

Comment: I edited my answer with what your code should look like.

Comment: I edited my answer, now its working. You need to recreate the motion events after onSizeChanged() is called, otherwise the mCanvas wont the initialized with the new screen dimensions and the view will be empty. Remember to remove android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" from your manisfest and to give the view an id so it can be recreated.

Comment: no it is not working... And when try write K it is not good K

Comment: did you removed android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" line from the activity in your manisfest file and set an id for the view?

Comment: i edited my answer so you can see how you can set your view id.